# Copying Shipping to Billing address if button is checked using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to have the shipping address copied to the billing when we clicked the checkbox, but it does not work

This is the HTML

```
<h1>JavaScript Homework</h1>
    <p>Add the JavaScript code needed to enable auto-complete on this form.  Whenever the checkbox is checked, the code should automatically copy the values from Shipping Name and Shipping Zip into the Billing Name and Billing Zip.  If the checkbox is unchecked, the Billing Name and Billing Zip should go blank.</p>

<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Shipping Information</legend>
        <label for ="shippingName">Name:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "shipName" id = "shippingName" required><br/>
        <label for = "shippingZip">Zip code:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "shipZip" id = "shippingZip" pattern = "[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" id="same" name="same" onchange= "billingFunction()"/>
    <label for = "same">Is the Billing Information the Same?</label>

    <fieldset> 
        <legend>Billing Information</legend>
        <label for ="billingName">Name:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "billName" id = "billingName" required><br/>
        <label for = "billingZip">Zip code:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "billZip" id = "billingZip" pattern = "[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
    </fieldset>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Verify"/>
    </form>
```

And my JavaScript

```
function billingFunction(){
 var SN=document.getElementById('shippingName').value;
  var SZ=document.getElementById('shippingZip').value;
  var BN=document.getElementById('billingName').value;
  var BZ=document.getElementById('billingZip').value;
  if (document.getElementById('same').checked==true){ BN=SN;BZ=SZ}
else {BN="";BZ=""}
}
```

I don't know why it does not work. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Define "it does not work". You might want to check out the FAQ on how to ask questions.

Comment: Clue #1: You get values then do nothing with them. You set then to local variables which are immediately discarded. Search the web for how to set a form field value.

Comment: Thanks, I worked it out

Comment: Cool-good to hear.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the values to a variable without doing anything with them.
This will work:

```
var SN = document.getElementById("shippingName");
var SZ = document.getElementById("shippingZip");
var BN = document.getElementById("billingName");
var BZ = document.getElementById("billingZip");

function billingFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById("same").checked == true) {
    BN.value = SN.value;
    BZ.value = SZ.value;
  } else {
    BN.value = "";
    BZ.value = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is helpful, I will need to add  {BN.value="" ; BZ.value="";} to make the else work also.

Answer (score 0):

you can try these

```
    const billingFunction = () => {
    const checkbx = document.getElementById('same')

    if(checkbx.checked){
        const shippingName = document.getElementById('shippingName')
        const shippingZipCode = document.getElementById('shippingZip')
        document.getElementById('billingName')
        document.getElementById('billingZip')
        billingName.value = shippingName.value
        billingZip.value = shippingZip.value
    } else {
        document.getElementById('billingName').value = "";
        document.getElementById('billingZip').value = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: On a scale of 1 to 10, where would you rate that code? It does not work, it is not formatted correctly, there are unused statements...